# Raytracing in Julia

Tags: julia

This is my first project in julia. It is a raytracer based on spheres.

```
using Random: rand, seed!, randn
using LinearAlgebra: norm, normalize, ×, ⋅
using Statistics: mean
using ImageCore: RGB, ⊙, clamp01
using FileIO: save

±(a, b) = @. a + [-1, +1] * b

Black = RGB{Float32}(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
White = RGB{Float32}(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
Gray = RGB{Float32}(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
Red = RGB{Float32}(0.8, 0.0, 0.0)
Blue = RGB{Float32}(0.0, 0.0, 0.8)
LightCyan = RGB{Float32}(0.2, 0.5, 0.9)
Yellow = RGB{Float32}(0.9, 0.9, 0.0)

struct Sphere
    center::Vector{Float32}
    radius::Float32
    albedoColor::RGB{Float32}
    emissionColor::RGB{Float32}
    reflectionColor::RGB{Float32}
    reflectivity::Float32

    function Sphere(
        center::Vector{<:Number},
        radius::Number,
        albedoColor::RGB{Float32},
        emissionColor::RGB{Float32} = Black,
        reflectionColor::RGB{Float32} = White;
        reflectivity::Number = 0.0,
    )
        return new(
            convert(Vector{Float32}, center),
            convert(Float32, radius),
            albedoColor,
            emissionColor,
            reflectionColor,
            convert(Float32, reflectivity),
        )
    end
end

struct Ray
    origin::Vector{Float32}
    direction::Vector{Float32}
    originSphere::Union{Sphere,Nothing}

    function Ray(origin::Vector{Float32}, direction::Vector{Float32})
        return new(origin, direction, nothing)
    end
    function Ray(origin::Vector{Float32}, direction::Vector{Float32}, sphere::Sphere)
        return new(origin, normalize(direction), sphere)
    end
end

function CalculateClosestIntersection(sphere::Sphere, ray::Ray)::Float32
    u = ray.direction
    CE = ray.origin - sphere.center
    r = sphere.radius

    b = u ⋅ CE
    c = b^2 - (norm(CE)^2 - r^2)

    return c < 0 ? Inf : begin
        λ = -b ± sqrt(c)
        minimum(filter(x -> x > 0, λ); init = Inf)
    end
end

function FindClosestHitPoint(
    scene::Vector{Sphere},
    ray::Ray,
)::Union{Tuple{Vector{Float32},Sphere},Missing}
    otherSpheres = filter(sphere -> sphere != ray.originSphere, scene)
    distances = map(sphere -> CalculateClosestIntersection(sphere, ray), otherSpheres)

    closestInd = argmin(distances)
    dist = distances[closestInd]

    if isfinite(dist)
        return (ray.origin + dist * ray.direction, otherSpheres[closestInd])
    else
        return missing
    end
end

function CreateEyeRay(
    eye::Vector{Float32},
    lookAt::Vector{Float32},
    fov::Float32,
    pixel::Vector{Float32},
)::Ray
    up = [0, 1, 0]
    f = normalize(lookAt - eye)
    r = normalize(up × f)
    u = normalize(f × r)
    d = normalize(f + sum([r, u] .* pixel * tan(fov / 2)))

    return Ray(eye, d)
end

function BRDF(sphere::Sphere, outgoing::Ray)::RGB{Float32}
    normal = normalize(outgoing.origin - sphere.center)
    reflectionDir = -outgoing.direction + 2 * normal * (normal ⋅ outgoing.direction)
    if (outgoing.direction ⋅ reflectionDir) > (1 - (1 / sphere.reflectivity))
        return (sphere.albedoColor + sphere.reflectionColor * sphere.reflectivity) * (1 / π)
    else
        return sphere.albedoColor * (1 / π)
    end
end

function SampleRandomSurfaceRay(
    origin::Vector{Float32},
    surfaceNormal::Vector{Float32},
    originSphere::Sphere,
)::Ray
    while true
        d = rand(Float32, 3) .* 2 .- 1

        if norm(d) > 1
            return Ray(origin, d * sign(d ⋅ surfaceNormal), originSphere)
        end
    end
end

function ComputeColor(scene::Vector{Sphere}, ray::Ray)::RGB{Float32}
    hitPoint = FindClosestHitPoint(scene, ray)
    if ismissing(hitPoint)
        return Black
    else
        intersection, sphere = hitPoint
        if rand(Float32) > p
            n = normalize(intersection - sphere.center)
            sampledRay = SampleRandomSurfaceRay(intersection, n, sphere)
            d = sampledRay.direction

            res =
                sphere.emissionColor +
                BRDF(sphere, sampledRay) * 2π * (d ⋅ n) ⊙ ComputeColor(scene, sampledRay) *
                (1 / (1 - p))
        else
            return sphere.emissionColor
        end
    end
end

function render(
    scene::Vector{Sphere},
    eye::Vector{Float32},
    lookAt::Vector{Float32},
    fov::Float32,
    width::Int,
    height::Int,
    numSamples::Int,
)::Matrix{RGB{Float32}}
    img = zeros(RGB{Float32}, width, height)
    σ = 0.5 / width

    Threads.@threads for i = 1:height
        x = range(-1, 1; length = height)[i]
        println("Rendering Line ", i)
        for (j, y) in enumerate(range(1, -1; length = width))
            img[j, i] = mean(
                ComputeColor(scene, CreateEyeRay(eye, lookAt, fov, Float32[x+dx, y+dy])) for (dx, dy) in eachrow(σ * randn(numSamples, 2))
            )
        end
    end

    return img::Matrix{RGB{Float32}}
end

function gammaCorrection!(img::Matrix{RGB{Float32}}, γ = 2.2)
    for i ∈ 1:length(img)
        c = img[i]

        img[i] = RGB{Float32}(c.r^(1 / γ), c.g^(1 / γ), c.b^(1 / γ))
    end
end

seed!(42)
p = 5.0f-2

scene = [
    Sphere([-1001, 0, 0], 1000, Red),
    Sphere([1001, 0, 0], 1000, Blue),
    Sphere([0, 0, 1001], 1000, Gray),
    Sphere([0, -1001, 0], 1000, Gray),
    Sphere([0, 1001, 0], 1000, White, 2 * White),
    Sphere([-0.6, -0.7, -0.6], 0.3, Yellow),
    Sphere([0.3, -0.4, 0.3], 0.6, LightCyan; reflectivity = 100f0),
]

eye = Float32[0, 0, -4]
lookAt = Float32[0, 0, 6]
fov = deg2rad(36.0f0)

width = 128
height = 128
numSamples = 64

@time img = render(scene, eye, lookAt, fov, width, height, numSamples)
gammaCorrection!(img)
save("out.png", map(clamp01, img))
```

The following image is a sample output produced:

[image: out.png]

**I would like to get feedback on the following aspects**:

- How could my code be rewritten to be more idiomatic julia?
- Ideas on how to improve readability
- How could the performance be improved without sacrificing readability?
- What would be an elegant solution to group the colors instead of declaring all color constants in the global namespace?

Comment: https://juliagraphics.github.io/Colors.jl/stable/namedcolors/